# JMeter - do not pass post value in post data if null

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter script, I have one HTTP request which has 4 different parameters to be passed in post body. I have corresponding variables. Values of these variables are not available every time, depending on configuration.

If a value is not available, I get an error "bad request". How do I see if a variable is not null and only then pass corresponding parameter in request post body?

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the following configuration:

[image: Example HTTP Request]

and you don't want to send `foo` parameter if `${bar}` variable is not defined

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of your HTTP Request Sampler
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   if (vars.get("bar") == null) {
       sampler.getArguments().removeArgument("foo");
   }
   ```

Where:

- `vars` - is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
- `sampler` - shorthand to parent sampler implementation class instance, in this case - [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Java and JMeter API from Beanshell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Logic Controller - If Controller. It allows to define the if statement using your variables. So, you can perform your actions only in case all parameters are not equal to null:
[image]
I've defined one single User Defined Variable in this example. Jmeter sends HTTP request only if it has a value defined.