# Temporarily removing an argument from a JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is that I am sending HTTP requests within a loop, in which the arguments values are based on JMeter variables. When first entering the loop I might have variables which are not set at this point, so they are null, hence I’d like to remove the argument from the HTTP request. I can successfully do so with the code below. However, at a later loop-iteration, this variable could now have a value and I would like to include the argument which I have previously removed. So my question is, how can I temporarily remove the argument from my HTTP request?

I have a JMeter Test Plan extract according to:

- While Controller

  - Some logic
  - HTTP Request

    - JSR223 PreProcessor (groovy)

My HTTP Request has the following arguments:

Name Value

inputA ${A}

inputB ${B}

My PreProcessor script looks like:

```
  for (Iterator iterator = sampler.getArguments().iterator();
      prop = iterator.next();
      String value = prop.getStringValue();
      if (value.contains('\${')) {
          iterator.remove();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I was trying your solution with a simple post call and it didn't work for me. Am I missing something? I am actually running api tests with parameters from CSV and my goal is to provide the parameter with empty string when it's value is empty string and remove parameter, when I provide a string like 'nullValue'.
The JSON body
{
  "ID" : "nullValue"
}
Script:
for (Iterator iterator = sampler.getArguments().iterator();
        prop = iterator.next();
        String value = prop.getStringValue();
        if (value.contains('nullValue')) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem could be to make a clone of the sampler Arguments object and set it to the sampler.

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
    Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments().clone();
    sampler.setArguments(arguments);
    for (Iterator iterator = sampler.getArguments().iterator();
        prop = iterator.next();
        String value = prop.getStringValue();
        if (value.contains('\${')) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The fastest, the easiest and imho the correct solution would be using [__evalVar()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) JMeter Function like:

   [image: JMeter EvalVar Function]

   So in case if `${A}` variable is not defined - `inputA` parameter will be sent with an empty value and such parameters are ignored by the well-behaved applications. See series of [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) guides to get started with JMeter Functions
2. I recall answering something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229607/2897748), it assumed checking if the variables is null using [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/)
3. If for some reason points 1 and 2 are not applicable, here is correct code to completely remove the parameter:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;

   Arguments args = sampler.getArguments();
   Iterator it = args.iterator();

   while (it.hasNext()) {
       def argument = it.next();
       if (argument.getStringValue().contains('${')) {
           args.removeArgument(argument.getName());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, as for (1), the application actually does not ignore blank values. As for (2) and (3), the problem remains that once I remove the argument, I cannot use it later in the loop. Assume that I will iterate over the loop 2 times. First time vars.get(“A”) = null, I will remove the argument. Second time vars.get(“A”) = foo, now I can't apply this value.
As for (3), using this code, I would run into java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.
Maybe I'll be able to save the arguments in bsh.shared, before I modify them, and then set them back in a post-processor. I'll try this next.

Comment: Then go the other way: make the blank request with no arguments initially and conditionally add the arguments if the associated variable value exists.